# Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-security

I have an application in Spring 5 and I am getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:281)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:615)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741)
        ... 85 more
```

My dependecies are:

```
<properties>        
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <springframework.version>5.1.4.RELEASE</springframework.version>    
    <springsecurity.version>5.1.4.RELEASE</springsecurity.version> 
    <hibernate.version>5.4.4.Final</hibernate.version>  
    <hibernate.validator>5.4.3.Final</hibernate.validator>  
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.46</mysql.connector.version>   
    <jackson.version>2.9.6</jackson.version>        
    <joda-time.version>2.9.9</joda-time.version>        
    <testng.version>6.14.3</testng.version>         
    <mockito.version>1.10.19</mockito.version>  
    <h2.version>1.4.197</h2.version>        
    <dbunit.version>2.5.4</dbunit.version>      
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>   
</properties>
```

I am getting this exception since I start the migration process from the Spring 4 to Spring 5. It worked fine before. 
Here also have one of the two hibernate configuration and the full exception error:
https://pastebin.com/UmPjQMNf

Comment: Please add the dependencies you are using, apparently you are mixing hibernate/spring versions that aren't compatible.

Comment: You are probably using an incompatible combination of libraries. You could use the [Spring Framework BOM](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-maven-bom) (bill-of-materials) instead of trying to specify the exact versions of all the libraries yourself - the BOM will give you a set of library versions that have been tested to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@M. Deinum was right it is the

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
    <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
</dependency>
```

When I removed it, it works fine!